# double ball bearing vs single ball bearing ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan, ball-bearing

I ordered two **Havells** fans from online.  I received two types with almost the same features except the following one, which is:

1. Double ball bearing ceiling fan
2. Single ball bearing calling fan

I am confused now, which one is better? Which is newest? Which one I need to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double bearing fan will have a longer life than a single bearing fan. The double bearing fan will have a bearing supporting the motor and fan shaft in two locations, rather than one.

A single bearing fan may have a bushing, or just a cantilevered shaft. This will cause the fan to be more difficult to balance and more susceptible to wear.